# search as you type with elasticsearch,angularjs

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, n-gram

I am working on search as you type functionality with angularjs and elastic search.I am passing the $viewValue to factory written in angular and it fetches data from angular.Please check code below.

---

```
services.factory('instantSearch',['$q', 'esFactory', '$location', function($q, elasticsearch, $location){

return{
instantResult : function(term){
 var client = elasticsearch({
// host: $location.host() + ':9200'
host: 'localhost:9200'
});
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    client.search({
      "index": 'stocks',
      "type": 'stock',
      "body": {
      "from" : 0, "size" : 20,
        "query": {
          "bool":{
            "should":[
            {
                "match_phrase":{
                      "name": term
                    }
            },
            {   
                "match_phrase":{
                "symbol": term
                }
            },
            {   
                "match":{
                "industry": term
                }
            }
        ]
          }

        }
      }
    }).then(function(result) {
    var hits = result.hits.hits;
    deferred.resolve(hits);
    }, 
    function (err) {
    console.trace(err.message);
    }, deferred.reject);
   return deferred.promise;
   }
   };

   }]);
```

---

This code is working fine but the problem is that I get result when input matches complete term in elasticsearch index's field.So I want to implement token analyzer which will match token(ngram - 1,2,3) and provide result on typing of each character.

So to add analyzer code we have to add settings in te elasticserach index as below:

```
 "settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "autocomplete_filter": { 
                "type":     "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 20
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
                "type":      "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "autocomplete_filter" 
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not getting the way to pass the argument here.Every example I checked shows output with curl command.How can we mix analyzer with the working code above.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the analyzer to the fields name, symbol and industry in your elastic search mapping?

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/_mapping?ignore_conflicts=true' -d'
{
    "type": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type":     "string",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Use ignore_conflicts=true without fail.

If you still face issues, then you might have to create a new index, add analyzer and filter to setting, create the desired mapping and then upload the data again.